# Как преобразовать записи из экселя в классы с полями?

Tags: java

Есть электронная таблица, в первом столбце идут наименования классов, во втором - в ячейкаx прописаны поля классов. Каким образом можно считать данные из ячеек и скомпилировать их в классы и поля?

Comment: Думаю вопрос с чтением файла не стоит. Класс ищешь с помощью  Class.forName и после, используя рефлексию, создаешь заполеннные инстансы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

читать эксель (если это не csv, а эксель) можно с помощью библиотеки https://poi.apache.org/

что значит "*скомпилировать*"?

- если имеется в виду простое инстанциирование, то создать экземпляры можно с помощью стандартной рефлексии, как уже упоминалось в комментарии к вопросу
- если же речь идет о генерировании кода, то нужно будет создавать файлы опять таки с помощью стандартных средств вывода (см java.nio.file) и последующего вызова компилятора (см javax.tools)